# How to listen nginx port 80 to django server?

Tags: django, nginx

Why nginx run default page ? how to listen my django server ?

First inside the `sites-availabe` folder i created `example.com` file then i

```
[root@instance-4 sites-available]# ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 21 Dec 22 11:03 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com -> example.com
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

Then when i run `gunicorn example.wsgi` in my app folder and later i visited the `example.com` but you know what i am still getting nginx default page.

What i am missing here ?

**Updated :**

Now this time i created example.com file in my Django root folder then after Symlink

```
[root@instance-4 Staging]# ln -s example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

after the nginx restart still same ...

**Updated 2** :

nginx.conf file

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: Your ls seems strange. sites-enabled/example.com seems to be linked to itself, and not to sites-available/example.com.

Comment: @DanielRoseman those are 2 dirs , available and enabled

Comment: Did you forget to reload the server?

Comment: @DRC yes two but `@Daniel` is correct see this [configure-nginx-for-your-site](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#configure-nginx-for-your-site). I got confused which one i follow ...

Comment: @BurhanKhalid after the nginx restart i run gunicorn example.wsgi ...

Answer (score 1):

Check for a `default` in `/etc/nginx/site-enabled/` and remove it if it's there. Then reload or restart your nginx server.

You can also check gunicorn is serving requests by visiting `example.com:8000`.

It's worthwhile noting that you'll probably also want nginx to be serving your static files so put in a `/static/` block:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /path/to/your/app/static/;
    if ($query_string) {
        # If using GET params to control versions, set to max expiry.
        expires max;
    }
    access_log off;
}
```

Comment: See gunicorn is running( http://127.0.0.1:8000 ) And in my above configuration means i can able to see the html content of my django in example.com .. right ? but i am seeing only nginx default page ..

Comment: no actually i'm setting this up on google cloud computing So port 8000 i can't access ...

Comment: ah okay - just a suggestion. Make sure you've removed that `default` and and check the `sites-enabled` folder is being included in your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` (there should be a line: `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`)

Comment: by default nginx sites-enabled folder is not there . i only create that.. is that ok ?

Comment: see there is no tutorial there .. see this [page](http://www.jodohost.com/blog/entry/setting-up-django-server-using-nginx-and-gunicorn/#) they mentioning `sites-available` only but i am using `sites-enabled` what should i follow ..

Comment: generally you create the file in `sites-available` and then symlink to it in `sites-enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

From what i remember of nginx, there is 2 places where you can find the index.html of nginx, try to do a "find / -name index.html" you will prolly find the 2nd .html i am talking about, and regarding the path u should be able to fix this

Comment: Please include more detail in your answer.